# Creating variable that can contain different classes

Tags: c++, class, variables

I want to make a variable something like `enum` witch is a pointer to a a class A, class B or empty.

It would look something like this:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"


enum Foo{
 A,
 B,
 Empty
};

int main(){
  Foo bar = new A();

  bar.print();

  bar = Empty;
  if ( bar == Empty )
    // do stuff
  return 0;

}
```

Is there something like this possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you think about using polymorphism?

I guess pointers suit here the best. The pointer to the base class can point on one of its children or null/0 as well - pretty much what you wanted.

If your `A` and `B` can inherit from common base class:

```
class A : public Base{...};
class B : public Base{...};
```

your code could look something like this:

```
int main(){
    Base * bar = new A();

    bar->print();

    delete bar; //to release A
    bar = 0;

    if(bar == 0){
       // do stuff   
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Also, to use `bar->print()` like that, make sure you declared it firstly in `Base` class (so the compiler knows that any type assigned to `Base * bar` can use it, e.g.:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void print(){...} 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, this suits much better.